# How to create a pivot table/chart for quarter data?

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2013

I am trying to create a pivot table that I can get the top 10 categories by quarter using the table below based on the numbers.  In conjunction, I want to make a pivot chart that will allow me to select what quarter I want to show as well.  Is this even possible?  Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that you don't have an answer yet because this is poorly tagged?

Anyway, here's a quick stab, seeing as nobody else has stepped up to the plate yet.

If your data was in an Excel worksheet then you could easily make this into a Pivot Table, simply highlight all the data and Insert - Pivot Table.  You would wants your rows to be "Category Association", and then you could add "QTR1" to "QTR4" as "Sum of" items to the "Values" part of the Pivot Table.

To get the top 10 per quarter you would need to click the arrow in the "Row Labels" cell and pick "More Sort Options".  Then "Descending (Z to A) by:" pick "Sum of QTR1", then "Sum of QTR2", etc.  If you want all four at the same time then make four pivot tables.  To get the top ten you would either count the rows manually, or use formulae to present this on another worksheet.

You can make a pivot chart by simply clicking the pivot chart button when you have a pivot table selected.  You can then select which quarters to include by ticking/ unticking them in the "Pivot Table Fields" section, but note that this will also affect the pivot table you picked to make into a pivot chart.  Again, you might need to make a new pivot table to be used for this purpose?

So everything on your list is possible, it's just a case of trying it I guess?

Comment: This actually helped getting it from another perspective.  I appreciate the assist.